# Flag a profile that contains specific offenses

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

Is it possible to use a red flag to indicate a profile that contains offenses?

Comment: Thanks! It's a good and valid question. It has already been answered on the main meta site: [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users). But as it's on another site, I don't close it as a duplicate, since Josephs answer brought it to the point and it's good to have it here.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I do my best and am not an expert on all sites :-(. thank you for the thanks that seems to me too much. I just want to stay serene. I really like this community but I only ask for a bit of sensitivity. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

Not really, unfortunately: the best one can do is flag a post by the user and explain in the comment.

Comment: I have removed comments here pointing to a specific user profile: the moderator team can see these

Comment: I actually have a question: is it inappropriate to link your profile to some specific events (such as edits). Asked differently, are events public (for those who have a high enough reputation to see them), and if so is it inappropriate to link them in a profile and/or meta post? If that's the case, is there a complete set of rules spelled out somewhere? (I fully understand that one may say that it is not good style to do certain things but I am really unsure where the border is, and whether the sheer link to some event without any personal statement on those involved is already forbidden.)

Comment: AFAIK, if there are no posts/comments by that user to be flagged, then it's acceptable to flag *any* post and explain very clearly the case (also, **must have a link to the offending user**)